# Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

For some odd reason my .getJSON() function isn't working. It is giving me this error message: `Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0`,
I really don't know whats happening.

Here's my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Hello from riskanalysis.delete.js");

    var categoryTd = $('#categoryId');
    var categoryText = categoryTd.text();
    var categoryInt = parseInt(categoryText);


    console.log(categoryInt);
    console.log(categoryText);


    console.log("Hello before");
    $.getJSON("/riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById?categoryId=" + categoryInt)
            .done(function (categoryName) {
                // On success
                console.log("Category name is: " + categoryName);
                categoryTd.text(categoryName); 
            }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) { var err = textStatus + ", " + error; console.log("Request Failed: " + err); });

    console.log("Hello after");
});
```

My controller code:

```
        [Route("riskanalysis/getCategoryNameById")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId)
        {
            return _manager.GetCategoryNameById(categoryId);
        }
```

My manager code:

```
        public string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId)
        {
            using (var dbContext = new Entities.DanoneRiskanalysisContext())
            {
                Entities.Category entitiy = dbContext.Category
                .Where(c => c.Id.Equals(categoryId))
                .FirstOrDefault();
                if (entitiy != null)
                {
                    return entitiy.ListCategories;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My manager interface code:

```
string GetCategoryNameById(int categoryId);
```

My .cshtml code:

```
  <tr>
     <td>Category</td>
     <td id="categoryId">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.categoryId)</td>
  </tr>
```

Here's the error message:

[image]

Here's the network tab:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Thanks already!

Comment: if you inspect the response in the browser developer tools, what does the response look like - perhaps the server isn't sending JSON

Comment: What do you mean by inspecting the response? I can't really seem to do anything with it in the browser developer tools? @JaromandaX

Comment: Check the Network tab

Comment: Just added a picture of the network tab. @Pointy

Comment: click on the request that fail, then check the response tab - as a web developer you'll find the tools in browser developer tools invaluable for debugging

Comment: or, try changing `$.getJSON` to `$.ajax`

Comment: Changing it to  ```$.ajax``` fixed it! I find this really weird since i used this same method before and it always worked until now. Thanks alot! @JaromandaX

Comment: the reason that fixed it is that your server isn't sending JSON - it seems to be sending plain text

Comment: Alright makes sense, thanks alot for your time. If you put this as a valid answer i can check it for you :) @JaromandaX

Comment: I haven't given you an answer - the $.ajax was a suggestion to determine if the server is actually sending JSON :p